# How to add parameters to function used in django cron jobs? (django-crontab)

Tags: python, django, cron

```
CRONJOBS = [('* * * * *', 'tweets.cron.get_tweets')]
```

I can't add any parameter to this function and it doesn't work since it requires parameters.
I wanna add something like

```
get_tweets(username)
```

Comment: What would the username be? Where would it come from?

Comment: It was just an example. Let say 'username'.

Comment: Well my point was, if it's a static value, why can't you write a wrapper function called `get_tweets_for_username` that just calls `get_tweets(username)`?

Comment: Actually, I have done this but i just wonder is there any way to add any parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this?

```
('* * * * *', 'tweets.cron.get_tweets', ['username'])
```

---> [docs](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab) <---